App works locally, but listening on forever when deployed to shinyapps.io
I have a shiny application running in docker that works locally without issues.
However, when I deploy to https://www.shinyapps.io/ , the app just hangs until timeout is reached.
This is the log I get, which seems fine to me:
2024-05-07T14:10:51.130589+00:00 shinyapps[11952779]: Running on host: 8f6f3bea3555
2024-05-07T14:10:51.136144+00:00 shinyapps[11952779]: Running as user: uid=10001(shiny) gid=10001(shiny) groups=10001(shiny)
2024-05-07T14:10:51.141129+00:00 shinyapps[11952779]: Connect version: 2023.10.0
2024-05-07T14:10:51.145931+00:00 shinyapps[11952779]: LANG: C.UTF-8
2024-05-07T14:10:51.151375+00:00 shinyapps[11952779]: Working directory: /srv/connect/apps/komgat1oraandgsea
2024-05-07T14:10:51.155767+00:00 shinyapps[11952779]: Using R 4.4.0
2024-05-07T14:10:51.160391+00:00 shinyapps[11952779]: R.home(): /opt/R/4.4.0/lib/R
2024-05-07T14:10:51.164939+00:00 shinyapps[11952779]: Content will use current R environment
2024-05-07T14:10:51.169310+00:00 shinyapps[11952779]: R_LIBS: (unset)
2024-05-07T14:10:51.173711+00:00 shinyapps[11952779]: .libPaths(): /usr/lib/R, /opt/R/4.4.0/lib/R/library
2024-05-07T14:10:51.179562+00:00 shinyapps[11952779]: shiny version: 1.8.1.1
2024-05-07T14:10:51.184272+00:00 shinyapps[11952779]: httpuv version: 1.6.15
2024-05-07T14:10:51.189120+00:00 shinyapps[11952779]: rmarkdown version: 2.26
2024-05-07T14:10:51.193919+00:00 shinyapps[11952779]: knitr version: 1.46
2024-05-07T14:10:51.198548+00:00 shinyapps[11952779]: jsonlite version: 1.8.8
2024-05-07T14:10:51.203091+00:00 shinyapps[11952779]: RJSONIO version: (none)
2024-05-07T14:10:51.207748+00:00 shinyapps[11952779]: htmltools version: 0.5.8.1
2024-05-07T14:10:51.212497+00:00 shinyapps[11952779]: reticulate version: (none)
2024-05-07T14:10:51.217016+00:00 shinyapps[11952779]: Using pandoc: /opt/connect/ext/pandoc/2.16
2024-05-07T14:10:51.221519+00:00 shinyapps[11952779]: 
2024-05-07T14:10:51.226204+00:00 shinyapps[11952779]: Starting R with process ID: '163'
2024-05-07T14:10:51.231828+00:00 shinyapps[11952779]: Shiny application starting ...
2024-05-07T14:10:51.236827+00:00 shinyapps[11952779]: 
2024-05-07T14:10:51.242241+00:00 shinyapps[11952779]: Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3839 

I have tried multiple ports but still it does not start the app in shiny.apps.io
Could someone help with this please?
Thank you

Have you set up a testing environment locally? Try golem framework.
